# Joomla on Azure Web App - performance issues

Tags: php, azure, joomla, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to get Joomla running on Azure Web Apps but the performance is terrible. 3-5 second response time no matter what operation I'm doing.

Tried the Bitnami VM and it runs much much smoother, so the problem is obviously in the web app. Have tried both Cleardb and the internal mysql preview db and both give the same laggy result. It doesn't matter what sized machines I run on, they all lag.

The only thing I haven't tried is upgrading the Cleardb database from the free tier to the paid ones, simply because my subscription doesn't allow it. Since I see the same performance issue with the internal mysql db this should not matter.

My guess is that this is an issue with PHP and IIS. Anyone with similar experience, and possibly a solution?

Comment: What did you scale your web app to? Did you try MySQL in a VM? These are your options (or running Joomla in a VM). Also, there are various web app settings you can tweak, when you scale to basic/standard plans (such as always on), and you can also try a Linux-based app service to see if it makes a difference. But... this really isn't a programming question (and as written, it's fairly open-ended / broad).

Comment: You can check out [this post](https://sunithamk.wordpress.com/2016/05/09/how-to-speed-up-joomla-web-app-on-azure-app-services/) on how to speed up Joomla Web App on Azure App Services.